# Раскодировка строки

Tags: шифрование

Перепробовал, считай, все кодировки.

```
4d44a0817b3718d14
```

Можете подсказать, что за кодировка?
Похоже на md5 сочитанием некоторых цифр и букв , но не расшифровывается.

ReinRaus Читай комментарии ... 
Gorets Если я бы не писал что это банк написал типо код к игрушке, вы бы к утру догадались, а прорраммисты в целях конфиденциальности информации с заданным вопросом "Откуда этот код" проверяя того кто это написал, и если ответ типо это какое-то гос учереждение просто закроете на это глаза скажете типо не расшифруешь... Вы не лезетти в эти дебри потому-что боитесь, а ведь страшно и одновременно интересно что это ?

Люди ну честно если кто реально знает что это и боиться писать сюда типо страница в поисковых системах индексируется напишите мне сюда seniarsen@mail.ru , письмо после прочтения честно удалю ...

Comment: я думаю это sha100500, попробуйте функцию sha100500_lol_decode(), я думаю это то, что вы ищите

Comment: Вообще чем это расшифровать ?

Comment: а где ты это взял?)) 100500_лол)

Comment: Банковская карта пароль защифрован

Comment: тогда вряд ли вскроешь.... вероятней всего это одностороннее шифрование

Comment: @Gorets - ты веришь в то, что ты можешь помочь человеку который пишет "Похоже на md5, но не расшифровывается"? :D

Comment: Та я просто бумашку с паролем от карты куда-то положил, а этот код для интереса в комп занёс , думаю вечерком на сайте спрошу может кто мельком встречался с этим... Вот с этим - 100500_лол) я никогда не встречался, есть онлаин дешифратор или програмка, думаю может выйдет... И вообще это как одностороннее  шифрование? , что типо не дешифруешь? Да и на каком языке программирования это sha100500_lol_decode()??? мне немного напоминает синтаксис С++...

Comment: @Gorets  Честно сказать я слез с компа и вкалываю в реальной жизни и не здесь за компом, я это дело немного подзабыл, просто как-то сочитаниями цифрами напоминает эту кодировку ... Думаю Можете помочь я немного знаю delphi и с, если нормально и не умничать то поможете ...

Comment: если бы было все так просто.. =) забыл пароль в банку =) расшифровал в инэете =) лоол 100500 - я думаю, это прикол ))))

Comment: А где Вы взяли этот "код"? У меня на картах такого нету.

Comment: ггг...А автор обладает долей иронии правда я сочувствую если он не шутит :).

"Вы не лезетти в эти дебри потому-что боитесь, а ведь страшно и одновременно интересно что это ?"

Дааа страааааашна...

"письмо после прочтения честно удалю"

А лучше перед прочтением.

Comment: Если считать, что   4d44a0817b3718d14 это 16-ричное число, то получается вот такое        55677515173152094254 десятичное.

Похоже ?

Comment: [Читай][1], горе-хакер. А вообще, не могу врубиться, откуда автор взял этот код...

  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: @RomanoO, а почему все решили, что это какой-то хэш-код ? 
Вот Вы явно о криптографии думаете. 

А я просто беззлобные шутки шучу.

Comment: я просто бумашку с паролем от карты куда-то положил, а этот код для интереса в комп занёс
Вы считаете, что из этой фразы очень понятно откуда появился этот "код" у Вас? Попробуйте ее прочитать несколько раз и осмыслить, восстановив причинно-наследственные связи цепи событий появления у Вас "кода". Не получилось? Вот и ни у кого кто этим интересовался тоже.

Comment: "восстановив причинно-наследственные связи цепи событий появления у Вас кода" О_О

Comment: Естественно, поэтому можно предположить простейший вариант hex -> dec.

Comment: Хотел бы я увидеть то творение, что производит такую последовательность размером в 8,5 байт. @Programist Syvorov, подробненько опишите что и где вы сделали, что и откуда взяли. На картах, а тем более банковских, никто и никогда не будет хранить код, пароль или пин, не важно как вы его называете.

Comment: Ааа, это же сверхсикретный пусковой код! Сутулов Арсентий 1993 г/р, за вами уже охотицца Моссад!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это действительно сильно похоже на хэш md5. Проблема здесь в том, что хэш это **необратимое** преобразование строки в другую строку. Ключевое слово - необратимое. То есть такой же хэш теоретически может иметь бесконечное количество других строк.

Все т.н. методы обращения хэша - опираются на то, что юзер мог ввести некую удобоваримую строку похожую на реальное слово или фразу, цифру и проч. Методов масса - начиная от [brute-force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack) до [rainbow table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table)

Сходите в форумы [antichat](http://antichat.ru/) - там много умельцев ковыряться в хэшах их обращении и проч.

Comment: Маловато байт в исходной фразе для `md5`

Comment: При радужных таблицах в 2ТБ для 64х битного ключа А5/1, я даже не могу представить необходимые объемы для md5.

Comment: md5 128-bit печатается строка из 32 hex, а здесь их 17 (68-bit)